# How can I avoid this error with mod_rewrite?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a site running on XAMPP on Windows. The root of the site is at localhost/sitename/.

I've used .htaccess with mod_rewrite to make index.php?app=appname appear at either sitename/appname/ or sitename/appname.

When I access an app through sitename/appname (without trailing slash), everything is fine. The browser finds my images and css at sitename/assets/.., as they are found relative to the current page.

The problem is, when I access an app through sitename/appname/ (with trailing slash), the browser cannot find my assets folder, as it is now trying to look in sitename/appname/assets/.

Without mod rewriting the assets folder, what can I do to fix this?

Comment: As much as possible please try to provide examples of the code/script which isn't working properly. In this case including the RewriteRule lines from the .htaccess, or the entire .htaccess file would help folks suggest how best to help you.

Comment: `RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?app=$1`
`RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ index.php?app=$1`

Answer (score 2):

> The problem is, when I access an app through sitename/appname/ (with trailing slash), the browser cannot find my assets folder, as it is now trying to look in sitename/appname/assets/.

The trailing slash is changing the base of your relative URI's. Without using mod_rewrite voodoo to fix this, you need to add the correct base in your page headers using the `<base>` tag:

```
<base href="/sitename/appname/">
```

or whatever the appropriate base should be.

Comment: I didn't know about the base tag, thanks. It works with absolute paths in the base tag and style tag. But, kinda reluctantly, I'll be using the full mod rewrite.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that without the slash your browser thinks that the current directory is `/sitename/` and that with the slash your browser thinks the current directory is `/sitename/appname/`.

So any asset with a relative path (not beginning with a forward-slash) such as `"assets/image.png"` will be assumed to be based in the current directory. To fix this you can either change all asset paths to an absolute path anchored to the root by starting the path with a forward-slash, so the previous example would become `"/sitename/assets/image.png"`. But I think, despite your desire to avoid a rewrite for the assets path, the following is simpler:

```
RewriteRule ^/sitename/appname/assets/(.+)$ /sitename/assets/$1
```

This will catch any lost requests for the non-existent `appname/assets` path and refer them to the correct `/sitename/assets` path.

Comment: Yeah, I've done the full mod rewrite. Thanks. Is this a common problem with trailing slashes? Is this how most sites would fix the problem?

Comment: Yes, silent rewrites frequently cause trouble with relative links (to images, style sheets, downloadable files, etc) within pages whose paths have been rewritten. As for the most popular solution, I don't know what the majority would choose, but so long as a solution works for you then it's the right one.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at how WordPress handles this problem when posts are viewed at index.php with address www.example.com/permalink-to-post/, it seems the best answer is to use absolute file paths to all links, images and CSS.

In this case, each link to the /assets/ folder should be `http://localhost/sitename/assets/`. (Until the site is on a live web server)